# Overloading methods of an Interface based on return type...

Tags: c#, interface, overloading

I cant seem to find anything that explicitly states this should never be done, not can i find a recommended method for doing it. so I am beginning to thing I am on an entirely wrong track here...

I am trying to overload a function based on return type in an interface. Basically I have 15 functions in an interface, 9 of them have the same name/params but different return type, I am trying to isolate this so I dont have to write 15 functions in the interface, I would just like a few..

```
public interface IController
{
    IEnumerable<T> Fetch<T>();
}
```

from here I want to do implementations such as...

```
    public IEnumerable<T> Fetch<T>() where T : *class*
    {
        return dbContext.*clas*.ToList();
    }
```

however I recieve a compilation error of...

```
Error   1   The constraints for type parameter 'T' of method 'Controllers.Controller.Fetch<T>()' must match the constraints for type parameter 'T' of interface method 'IController.Fetch<T>()'. Consider using an explicit interface implementation instead.
```

anyone have any ideas on this one...

Comment: You can't have the same method with different return types - Look at the [`Convert`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Convert_methods(v=vs.110).aspx) class to see that sometimes a lot of methods that vary just on return type are necessary.  You're going to end up with a lot of `Get{class}` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this because this implementation conflicts with the [*Liskov Substitution principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

> A method can only become more wide (accept more) than the the classes/interfaces above in the type hierarchy.

Now C# does not fully support the Liskov Substition principle (in the sense that widening parameters is not allowed). But it means for instance that if a method

```
public class Foo {

    void Bar (T parameter);

}
```

is defined in the first level, that method cannot be override with

```
public class SubFoo : Foo {

    void Bar (SubT parameter);

}
```

This is because one can call the `Bar` method of a `SubFoo` on the `Foo` level. And the `Foo` level has a contract that it accepts `T`. So making the types more narrow is not an option.

If one thus moves down in the class hierarchy one notices that:

- return types become more narrow; and
- parameters become wider

C# however supports *variance/covariance* on the interface level. If `T` is thus only used to specify the output type, one can indeed make `T` more narrow. This is called *variance*. You can specify this as:

```
public interface Foo<out T> {

    T GetValue ();

}
```

It means that `Foo<T>` is a subclass of `Foo<SuperT>`. The same for covariance:

```
public interface Foo<in T> {

    void SetValue (T value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Making a few assumptions...if you're talking about an EF dbContext, you can actually do this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Fetch<T>() where T : class
    {
        return dbContext.Set<T>().ToList();
    }
```

More generally, you can do something like this, where the generic method delegates to various implementation methods for the different types:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Fetch<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(X)) return FetchX();
        //Handle other types here...
    }
```

---

As Servy pointed out, to implement the above you would also need to modify your interface to include the class constraint (assuming you need it):

```
public interface IController
{
    IEnumerable<T> Fetch<T>() where T: class;
}
```

Comment: But he can't do that when the interface doesn't have the generic constraint.

Comment: @Servy, He can still have a generic method on the interface without a generic constraint on the interface.  Perhaps I've misunderstood the question though; it doesn't have an example of what is being replaced.

Comment: No, he can't.  He tried to do exactly that and got the exact error message in the quesiton.  You're just telling him to do exactly what he's already doing, and what he has demonstrated doesn't work.

Comment: @Servy, If I understand correctly, what the op is trying to do is create multiple implementations of the same interface method, using a different constraint for each one.  That doesn't work, of course; you can only implement the method once and it has to have the same constraints.  The general approach I've suggested only uses a single method implementation (matching the interface), then uses `typeof` checks to delegate appropriately to internal methods.

Comment: It doesn't matter if there is more than one or even a single one.  You cannot have an interface implementation in which the generic argument has constraints that the interface's generic method doesn't have.  If you try, you get the exact error message the OP is getting.

Comment: @Servy, Thanks, I see what you mean.  I used the class constraint in case this was an EF implementation (which would require a class constraint, I believe), but I neglected to mention that this constraint would also need to match on the interface.

Comment: Which is of course explicitly what the OP is trying to not do.